# Best K-fold Segmentation Cross-validation

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, image-segmentation

In image segmentation tasks, what validation metric is standard for model selection? I'm logging binary cross-entropy loss, Dice coefficient, and accuracy, but I don't know if I should use validation accuracy or Dice coefficient for model selection. What is standard? As a side note, what other metrics do people typically log?